# Combining two tables into one in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

In bigQuery, I have two tables - one with 30K records, and another with 20M records.

I need an efficient way to search them with a join, so I was thinking of creating a combined table with this SQL:

```
SELECT 
s.site site,
s.rank rank,
s.visitors visitors,
s.store_id store_id,
s.currency currency,
p.title title,
p.product_type product_type,
p.handle handle,
p.price price,
p.created_at created_at,
p.image_url image_url,
p.description description
FROM eComData.stores s INNER JOIN eComData.products p ON s.store_id = p.store_id
WHERE
s.active = 1
```

However, running this bq command:

```
bq query --destination_table=eComData.stores_n_products --allow_large_results "SELECT s.site site,s.rank rank,s.visitors visitors,s.store_id store_id,s.currency currency,p.title title,p.product_type product_type,p.handle handle,p.price price,p.created_at created_at,p.image_url image_url,p.description description FROM eComData.stores s INNER JOIN eComData.products p ON s.store_id = p.store_id WHERE s.active = 1"
```

is taking forever - 5,000 seconds plug so far. Is there an efficient way to create a combined table for easier searching?

Comment: If you are using legacy SQL (and it looks like you are) then filters are not automatically pushed through joins. You would either need to use a subquery or else pass `--use_legacy_sql=False` to `bq query`. See also the [standard SQL documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/).

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```sql
SELECT 
  s.site site,
  s.rank rank,
  s.visitors visitors,
  s.store_id store_id,
  s.currency currency,
  p.title title,
  p.product_type product_type,
  p.handle handle,
  p.price price,
  p.created_at created_at,
  p.image_url image_url,
  p.description description
FROM (
  SELECT   
    site,
    rank,
    visitors,
    store_id,
    currency
  FROM eComData.stores
  WHERE active = 1
) s 
INNER JOIN eComData.products p 
ON s.store_id = p.store_id
```

Comment: That seems quicker, but it's still taking a long time - although I'm not sure how long it'll take to do a join on 22M records.

Comment: Ok, so I've deleted any records from the eComdata.stores table where active = false, so I don't have to add the WHERE clause in there.

However, trying to select all that into a new table still runs into the thousands of seconds. Any ideas on how to get combined data this big into a table?